# India Visa to attend a conference

Tags: visas, india, e-visas

I'm Sri Lankan passport holder. I found Sri Lanka is in eVisa supported country list. Can I apply for eVisa to attend a conference for 4 days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an email from e-Visa support center.

> Dear applicant,
>
> evisa is not eligible for conference purposes
>
> Regards
>
> e- Visa support Team

Answer (score 2):

From what I have learnt on [India e-Visa page](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html), you can surely apply for eVisa.

Answer (score 2):

Since very recently (around November 2018?), it is possible to apply for a conference e-visa. See the [Indian e-visa website](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html).

Comment: Is it only for Government organize event?

Comment: I have the impression that in most cases yes, but it can be also NGO, etc. My understanding is that the conditions are the same as for the non-electronic conference visa, and I know a good summary at:
http://ivs-germany.com/ConferenceVisa.aspx